# Eclipse Plugin Development : Right Click Menu is not appearing after adding plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have written an Eclipse plugin and added it in eclipse. The plugin is working fine with the shortcut but after right clicking on the file, the menu is not appearing. And if I run this plugin in Runtime-Eclipse everything working fine.  Does anyone have any idea whats wrong ?

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            id="testMenu.commands.category"
            name="Sample Category">
      </category>
      <command
            categoryId="testMenu.commands.category"
            id="testMenu.commands.sampleCommand"
            name="Sample Menu">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="test.plugin.MenuHandler"
            commandId="testMenu.commands.sampleCommand">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="testMenu.commands.sampleCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="M1+6">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <menu
               id="testMenu.menus.sampleMenu"
               label="Menu"
               mnemonic="M">
            <command
                  commandId="testMenu.commands.sampleCommand"
                  id="testMenu.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S">
                    <visibleWhen>
                           <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                            <iterate
                                 ifEmpty="false">
                                  <or>
                             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                              <or>
                               <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.java" />
                                 <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.xml" />
                                 </or>
                             </adapt>
                               </or>
                            </iterate>
                           </with>
                    </visibleWhen>
            </command>
             </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
      <startup
            class="test.plugin.TaskManager"></startup>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

---

This is my plugin.xml file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you starting Eclipse with the `-clean` option to make sure the plugins cache is rebuilt?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `<with variable="selection">` in your `visibleWhen` of popup , because the selection is not actually menu, it is a file ?

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your reply, I used '-clean' but the problem is same.

Comment: Can you better explain when it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: It's working in Java perspective but not working in JavaEE perspective.